# How to run qpidd daemon, listening on 127.0.0.1 and not on 0.0.0.0

Tags: amqp

I haven't find any usefull information on qpid.apache.org how to start listening qpidd daemon 
on other address than 0.0.0.0. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not supported at the moment, at least not in the C++ broker.  I've created a JIRA for it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/QPID-3351